# Upload a FOLDER/DIRECTORY on aws s3 using sync command with wildcards

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to upload only directories whose names are ending with 0,1 and 2 on AWS using AWS s3 sync command. for example, I want to upload a directory name `anyname0`.

I know I can do this thing with files ending with a specific extension like this

```sh
aws s3 sync 'D:\TestData\Actual Data' s3://destination-AWSDOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/ --exclude "*" --include "*0.txt" --include "*1.txt" --include "*2.txt"
```

But is there any way to apply this thing on directories also? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this example using the following pattern

```sh
aws s3 sync 'D:\TestData\Actual Data' \
  s3://destination-AWSDOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/ \
  --exclude "*" \
  --include "*anyname0/**"
```

Example

```sh
$ tree
.
├── anyname0
│   ├── 6.txt
│   ├── 7.txt
│   ├── 8.txt
│   └── 9.txt
├── anyname1
│   ├── 6.txt
│   ├── 7.txt
│   ├── 8.txt
│   └── 9.txt
├── anyname2
│   ├── 6.txt
│   ├── 7.txt
│   ├── 8.txt
│   └── 9.txt
├── anyname3
│   ├── 6.txt
│   ├── 7.txt
│   ├── 8.txt
│   └── 9.txt
└── anyname4
    ├── 6.txt
    ├── 7.txt
    ├── 8.txt
    └── 9.txt
$ aws s3 sync ./ s3://my-bucket --exclude "*" --include "*anyname0/**" --dryrun
(dryrun) upload: anyname0/6.txt to s3://my-bucket/anyname0/6.txt
(dryrun) upload: anyname0/7.txt to s3://my-bucket/anyname0/7.txt
(dryrun) upload: anyname0/8.txt to s3://my-bucket/anyname0/8.txt
(dryrun) upload: anyname0/9.txt to s3://my-bucket/anyname0/9.txt
```

Can also do multiple patterns

```sh
$ aws s3 sync ./ s3://my-bucket --exclude "*" \
  --include "*anyname0/**" \
  --include "*anyname3/**" \
  --dryrun
(dryrun) upload: anyname0/6.txt to s3://my-bucket/anyname0/6.txt
(dryrun) upload: anyname0/7.txt to s3://my-bucket/anyname0/7.txt
(dryrun) upload: anyname0/8.txt to s3://my-bucket/anyname0/8.txt
(dryrun) upload: anyname0/9.txt to s3://my-bucket/anyname0/9.txt
(dryrun) upload: anyname3/6.txt to s3://my-bucket/anyname3/6.txt
(dryrun) upload: anyname3/7.txt to s3://my-bucket/anyname3/7.txt
(dryrun) upload: anyname3/8.txt to s3://my-bucket/anyname3/8.txt
(dryrun) upload: anyname3/9.txt to s3://my-bucket/anyname3/9.txt
```